# Python logging - logrotate options

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, logrotate

I am trying to use logrotate to rotate logs for a multi-process python service. Which of the following combination is commonly used (right and safe)?

- WatchedFileHandler + logrotate with create option

  OR
- FileHandler + logrotate with copytruncate option

Option-1 seem to be used in openstack nova and glance projects. I have not seen option-2 being used. Will option-2 work as expected?. Are there any drawbacks with these approaches when used for multi-process apps?

Comment: Re. multiple processes sharing files - see the documentation for more information: http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes - whether or not you use logrotate, doing this can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As `WatchedFileHandler` was provided specifically for use with external rotation tools like `logrotate`, I would suggest that it be used (Option 1). Why do you think you need Option 2?

In a multi-process environment where each process writes to its own logs, there shouldn't be any problems. However, processes shouldn't ever share log files.

Comment: Regarding option-2, I was trying to understand the pros and cons of these approaches(especially copytruncate). What are the possible issues which could happen with multiple processes sharing same log file? Doesn't services like redis where multiple instances of same redis is run on same box use this approach ? (Please correct me if i am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Python's own log rotation to get the best integration. The only drawback is that you have an additional place to configure the details.

Comment: RotatingFileHandler will not work with multiple processes sharing same file. And I don't want to use network loggers like SocketFileHandler and SyslogFileHandler.